# Modify the MPU3050 driver in linux kernel (Android) to use MPU6050

Tags: android, kernel, driver, accelerometer

I have a device to run (gsensor, MPU6050) with an Android system.
I can't build it directly because it does not exist with the 3.4 kernel, but I wonder if I can modify the MPU3050 driver for my device works.

I have found this [readme](http://kernel--tegra.android-source-browsing.googlecode.com/git-history/08f02f8bba6ec3613a3ca3d19e1a07f67739bdd4/drivers/staging/iio/imu/inv_mpu/README), but I wonder if it will work ?

**Edit:** After half of work*, here a part of `dmesg`:

```
<7>[   13.283019] i2c-core: driver [mpu3050] registered
<6>[   13.283119] init: command 'insmod' r=0    
<4>[   13.312403] industrialio: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
<6>[   13.315656] init: command 'insmod' r=0
<4>[   13.320725] kfifo_buf: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
<6>[   13.321687] init: command 'insmod' r=0
<4>[   13.329837] ring_sw: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
<6>[   13.330847] init: command 'insmod' r=0
<6>[   13.354793] hub 4-0:1.0: [hub_activate 872]
<4>[   13.392922] inv_mpu_iio: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
<7>[   13.395860] i2c-core: driver [inv-mpu-iio] registered
```

i2ctools detect this:

```
# i2cdetect -y 0
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: UU UU UU UU UU UU UU UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: UU UU UU UU UU UU UU UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
# i2cdetect -y 2
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: UU UU UU UU UU UU UU UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
# i2cdump -f -y 2 0x68
No size specified (using byte-data access)
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f    0123456789abcdef
00: 89 75 81 e1 1e 0f fb 1e fe 8d 00 a8 28 51 50 b9    ?u????????.?(QP?
10: 86 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ?...............
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00    ...........@....
70: 00 00 00 00 00 68 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    .....h..........
80: 89 75 81 e1 1e 0f fb 1e fe 8d 00 a8 28 51 50 b9    ?u????????.?(QP?
90: 86 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ?...............
a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00    ...........@....
f0: 00 00 00 00 00 68 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    .....h..........
# i2cget -f -y 2 0x68
0x75
# i2cget -f -y 2 0x68
0xe1
# i2cget -f -y 2 0x68
0x0f
# i2cget -f -y 2 0x68
0x1e
# i2cget -f -y 2 0x68
0x8d
#
```

*Just the drivers has been compiled, the kernel hasn't been modified. The following [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253104/writing-a-driver-i2c-for-mpc6050/30259536#30259536).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Consult the data sheets for the difference between the capabilities and registers of each device, but I believe you will find that the mpu-6050 is a superset of the mpu-3050 so extending a driver for one to accommodate the other should be a simple case of programming-by-example.

Your question as asked is borderline inappropriate here - Stackoverflow exists to provide assistance with *specific problems* and you have not stated any actual issue beyond wondering if it possible, to which the answer as given above is yes, provided that you do the work and learn from the resources available to you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your approbation. I wasn't sure that this 'patch' was written for this usage. And sorry for this wide question!

Comment: So, I have builded the drivers successfully, but I have problems with the `board-omap4panda.c` file. My board is different, and no such file in the `mach-sun7i` folder. I'm still searching but maybe I'll ask a new question tomorow with all the details.

Comment: Figure out how your existing drivers are specified in the kernel version you are using for your board - are they explicitly listed in a file with a similar role?  Or does it use device tree?   My impression is vendor sunxi kernels use the first, while community ones the second.  You can also see if building as a loadable module simplifies things.

Comment: I can see with lsmod `industrialio.ko`, `kfifo_buf.ko`, `ring_sw.ko` and `inv-mpu-iio.ko`. i2cdetect can see something but I don't know if it's really my device. But nothing in `/sys/bus/iio/devices/` it's empty. So I think I have done half of the work

Comment: Put lots of pritnk's in your driver and then with dmesg you can at least see if it is finding hardware.  i2cdetect is I believe using a userspace interface - that would be interesting too, as then you can have the logic of talking to the chip's various registers in userspace where it is easier to hack on.

Comment: Ah yes, good idea to rebuild the drivers with some prints. Thanks. I will play with it. The `board-omap4panda.c` is modified but I don't know if the kernel use it. And in `mach-sun7i/include/mach` folder, there's no .c file. Just .h (to define vars I suppose)

Comment: No it will not use the omap4panda - you have an allwinner part, not a TI omap.  You need to figure out how your built in peripherals *are* declared for your particular kernel,

Comment: Hi Chris, I have posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253104/writing-a-driver-i2c-for-mpc6050). Thanks